# VBA -Excel - How to replace a column letter to a column index in a Range function

Tags: excel, vba

I need to replace code
`Sheet5.Range("N2:N24").Value = Sheet1.Range("B9")` with something like `Sheet5.Range(Columns(14).Select & "2:" & Columns(14).Select & "24").Value = Sheet1.Range("B9")`

but it gives an error.
Basically I would like to replace the column letter with the index of the column.
How is the syntax?

Many thanks,
Electra

Comment: Use `Cells`, which accepts the column index as the second parameter.

Comment: `Sheet5.Range(Sheet5.Cells(2, 14),Sheet5.Cells(24,14)).Value`